# Trying to find a way to calculate Jodatime instants overlap with java8

Tags: datetime, java-8, jodatime

i am currently looking into migrating from JodaTime to java8 apis.

Most is ok, but one thing eludes me. I have the need to calculate how much of a persons work shift that falls within "office hours".

With JodaTime, i have utilized the Instant class to perform the calculation with roaring success:

```
DateTime in = new DateTime(inTime);
DateTime out = new DateTime(outTime);

Interval officeHours = new Interval(in.withTime(whstart.getHours(), 
whstart.getMinutes(), 0, 0),
in.withTime(whend.getHours(), whend.getMinutes(), 0, 0));

Interval shift = new Interval(in, out);
Interval overlap = officeHours.overlap(shift);

officeHoursSeconds = overlap != null ?
 overlap.toDuration().getStandardSeconds() : 0;
```

However, since the Interval class seems to be missing from java8, i am at a bit of a loss as to how best move this logic to the java8 api's.

I could continue using Jodatime of course, but since it's EOL'ed, i'd like to try and remove it completely.

Pointers much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Joda-class `Interval` has not been overtaken by Java-8**. I see mainly three ways:

a) Write your own interval class (looking into source code can help however)

b) Use my lib [Time4J](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J) and the class [MomentInterval](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/MomentInterval.html) with the method [findIntersection(...)](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/range/IsoInterval.html#findIntersection-net.time4j.range.ChronoInterval-) which yields an optional intersection interval. Conversion methods to Java-8-classes like `moment.toTemporalAccessor()` yielding `java.time.Instant` exist.

c) Use the lib [Threeten-Extra](https://github.com/ThreeTen/threeten-extra) which has a class with same name [Interval](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html) and its method [intersection(...)](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html#intersection-org.threeten.extra.Interval-). Here you have to check first if the intersection exists otherwise an exception will be thrown.

Comment: Thanks for chiming in Meno. I have one question though - not trying to be rude or anything. If my best solution is to include a third-party library of some kind, and i already include JodaTime, what would my upside be to learn a new one and switch to that? Again, not arguing just asking!

Comment: @Mathias Standard Java can never incorporate all aspects of time handling due to size constraints while 3rd-party libraries don't care about such constraints. See also what the [OpenJDK](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/150) has declared: "It is not a goal to solve all date/time problems, but the new API should be a suitable base for external extensions." About comparison of Joda-Time and other libs, well, Joda-Time is now only in maintenance mode (only bugfixing, no bigger enhancements) and - compared with Time4J - already lacks some things like astronomy, more calendars, interval handling etc.

Comment: @Mathias Actually, Joda-Time does not offer good interoperability with `java.time`, see also this unsolved old [issue](https://github.com/JodaOrg/joda-time/issues/254).

Comment: Sure, hear you. But all those things - astronomy, interoperability, more calendars etc - are not applicable to my specific use case. I basically only need to get the overlap and convert it to seconds. For everything else, the java8 api seems to do what i need.

Comment: @Mathias If you are still satisfied with Joda-Interval then it is okay to keep Joda. But if you are keen on getting rid of Joda then you might consider to implement your own simple interval class with just this overlap-method. Should not be so difficult if your interval-feature needs are so small. Maybe the source code of Threeten-Extra-Interval is a suitable start because it is simple/small enough and can easily be simplified further.

Comment: Right. Thanks for your great input. I'll keep Joda for now, and i'll see if i can find the time to do that... :) Marking this as answered, since you were helpful.